# Specify extended regex for cross platform find command

Tags: regex, find

In Ubuntu, to be able to use extended regex during a `find` you can specify the `-regextype` flag but in OSX it requires the `-E` flag. Is there a portable way to do the following?

`find app -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.+\.(handlebars|partial)'`

Comment: No, you cannot create a find command with extended regex support that works for both OSX and Ubuntu. -- You can however create an alias in both .bashrc files and construct a uniform find command like that but that would hardly be portable to a new machine without creating a new alias first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all ideal, but you could do something like

```
platform=`uname`
if [$platform='Darwin']; then
    find app -type f -E posix-extended -regex '.+\.(handlebars|partial)'
else
    find app -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.+\.(handlebars|partial)'
fi
```

Note that this will just assume linux if it's not OS X, and I think you need to check for a slightly different string then 'Darwin' on OS X, though it's something like that.

Comment: While the syntax for find was slightly incorrect this works well. Thanks!